# How to disable SSL certificate checking with Spring WebServiceTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, ssl

For testing purposes in a development environment, I want to ignore `https` certificate problems with my development servers.

My Web Service Client was getting :-

`PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

There are a number of similar Questions which helped me find the solution, but I thought I would post the answer to this specific question here for anyone who needs it....

Answer (score 13):

```
class UnTrustworthyTrustManager
        implements X509TrustManager
{
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)throws CertificateException {}
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
}
```

and then

```
setDefaultUri("https://myServer/soapws/ws/");
Source requestSource = new ResourceSource(new ClassPathResource("MyRequest.xml"));
StringResult result = new StringResult();
WebServiceTemplate template = getWebServiceTemplate();

HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender sender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
sender.setTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { new UnTrustworthyTrustManager() });
template.setMessageSender(sender);

template.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(requestSource, result);
System.out.println(result);
```

(requires spring-ws-support)

Comment: The above snippet will not work if you deploy it into Weblogic since WL will return instance of weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection for HTTPS connection instead of javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection expected by Spring-WS. To overcome this you have to tell WL to use Sun's HTTP handler instead by setting -DUseSunHttpHandler=true